# dygraph doesnt print the data in hidden div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dygraphs

I've been trying to use dygraph (http://dygraphs.com/) for visualization purpose in my website and it works fine with all the features. The website that I am trying to build is a dynamic one and at first I tried printing it on to a visible `div` element and it was fine.. Then I tried to introduce a `div` element which can be expanded and collapsed on click. so if I tried to print the graph with the `div` collapsed, it will not work, only when it is expanded, the graph gets printed.. I am adding a jsfiddle link to show my issue..

http://jsfiddle.net/dTUQC/2/

What could be the reason for this issue???

```
  $("#chartdiv").css({"height":"160px"});
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("chartdiv"), input, {
    width : 500,
    includeZero : true,
    animatedZooms : true,
    drawXGrid : false,
    plotter : barChartPlotter
});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind that is, since your are using the [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) function ,the display property is saved and restored as needed. the style of `div chartdiv` is `display : none` when closed... the bargraph couldn't get rendereded in that dom element. and whn it is open the style changes to `display:block` so this time the graph finds the `div chartdiv`.

here is the fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/dTUQC/3/

check the console.. where i have displayed the style...if i change the `div chartdiv` to `display:block` .. the graph is rendered even whn the div is in closed state..

**UPDATED**

OR use `.show()`..

http://jsfiddle.net/dTUQC/9/  **with one button**

Comment: bt the print button, opens the div..Im tryin to do it the other way.. when we click drawgraph it should print the graph, bt only when the open button is clicked, it should show t he graph.. that way it is nt working..

Comment: I wanna display the graph only when the user wants to view it..so i used .show() jquery function

Comment: ok i was jus giving  u the reasons why that was happening.... since your question was `what could be the reason for this issue???`...you can show the graph whn user clicks button.. instead of using two button....i think

Comment: if you add the functionality to different buttons.. printing and showing to two diff buttons.. and first click print graph and then click click on show button, it will nt show the graph..

Comment: yes i know.. that is what i wanted to explain,  why is that happening in my answer